# Do i need to purchase license of MySQL for my customized web based application

Tags: mysql

I am developing client server application using ASP.NET together with MySQL. This solution will be hosted using VPS and of course I will install MySQL in VPS.

This web based application is a customized solution based on my customer requirements and I have no idea whether I can use MySQL community edition or I have to pay?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can Someone Explain MySQL's License and What it Means to Closed Source Development?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/225987/can-someone-explain-mysqls-license-and-what-it-means-to-closed-source-developme)

Answer (score 1):

The question (and the answer) does not apply to MySQL only, but to all [GPL-licenced](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.en.html) software.

There is nothing to pay to *use* a piece of GPL software. MySQL Community edition is licensed under the [GPL-v2 licence](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html).

Comment: I have extracted the following from another post, 

"Yes, it does matter if you distribute MySQL with your project. MySQL uses the GPL License. This means that if you distribute GPL-licencsed technology (code or binary) then any of your code you distribute with it must also be licensed with the GPL. So your code becomes open-source too and you're obliged to make your source code available."

I have been reading similar statements everywhere but I cannot figure out the meaning of "distributing MySQL with your product", appreciate if you could provide an example.

Comment: @LuceriasLucer Basically, if you *distribute* your application (eg. a CD-ROM), then the licence applies and you must ask yourself if your application is a *derivative work*. Since you host the application, and do not *distribute* your code (source or binary), then the GPL licence does not apply to this case, because you *use* MySQL.

Comment: What if it is a windows form standalone application and backend is MySQL? But I do not distribute in CD form, I would go to client site and install MySQL and Windows form application in client PC/laptop, which scenario does this belong to?

Comment: @LuceriasLucer This situation is unclear and is [often subject to dispute](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License#Communicating_and_bundling_with_non-GPL_programs). My understanding is that this wouldn't constitute a derivative work, but **I am not a lawyer**.